# flask:how to stop python programs when jquery find an invalid input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, web, flask

Im new to Flask .
I try a user log-in page
I validate the user input by jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//alert('begin');
$(".input.reg_butn").click(function(){
    if($("[name=username]").val()==""){
        alert("username empty");
    }else{
        if($("[name=password]").val()==""){
            alert("password empty");
        }
    }
})
```

})

and my python code is as follow:

```
@app.route('/login',methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    .....
```

My question is how to stop python code running when the js code finds that the user submitted an invalid value (such as empty username of password).
I use alert in JS to notify the user, BUT the python code run as usual.
How to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the right approach: to validate data in on the client side. Instead you should do it on the server side using a flask extension which deals with forms and form validation: [flask-WTF](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#validating-forms).

Answer (score 0):

You are capturing the click of the input button, but you need to stop form submission. If you do this with a handler that listens to that instead, you will also be able to run your checks when the user presses the enter key.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Adjust this selector as necessary.
  $("form.login").submit(function() {
    $(this).preventDefault();

    if ($("[name=username]", this).val() == "") {
      alert("username empty");
    } else {
      if ($("[name=password]", this).val() == "") {
        alert("password empty");
      }
    }
});
```

If you are using HTML5, though, this can all be simplified by adding `required` to your input tags.

```
<input type="text" name="username" required>
```

[Any browser that supports it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation) will trap the form submission for you (without the need for any JavaScript).